# Creating user home folder from template folder

Tags: php, rest, alfresco

I have a model folder `"0000"` in a directory **A** in `alfresco` and whenever a new user is created , I have to create a folder for him with the same folder structure as the model folder , I found through rest api, that I can do that with this :

```
{"alf_destination": "workspace://SpacesStore/35818681-274f-4d61-8fe7-5cff238513e5",
"prop_cm_name": "0000",
"prop_cm_title": "",
"prop_cm_description": "",
"sourceNodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/aeeaca0a-89bf-4294-8506-315ecd7d18f2",
"parentNodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/35818681-274f-4d61-8fe7-5cff238513e5" 
}
```

but how can I get the that spacestore `/{id}` in php ? 
and I have created the dest folder via `ftp_mkdir` because I didn't understand how to do it with *alfresco* (*I didn't know what a {container} and site's name is* ) 
here is the path to the model : `/Alfresco/Dictionnaire de données/Modèles d'espace/0000`

and here where the new folders will be created : `/Alfresco/Data/users`
pardon my english and Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`userHomesHomeFolderProvider`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/person/UsernameHomeFolderProvider.html) that allows you inject [Home Folder Template](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/person/UsernameHomeFolderProvider.html#setTemplatePath-java.lang.String-). You can find its definition inside this library: [`tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-{ver}.jar/alfresco/authentication-services-context.xml`](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/authentication-services-context.xml):

```
<bean name="userHomesHomeFolderProvider" parent="usernameHomeFolderProvider">
    <property name="rootPath">       
       <value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.user_homes.childname}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="storeUrl">
        <value>${spaces.store}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

You can customize this bean as follows:

1. **Create the template folder** and its content (files, sub-folders,..), for example: `Repository> Data Dictionary> user_homes_templates> custom_home_root`
2. **Override the `userHomesHomeFolderProvider` bean definition** and inject the new property `templatePath` pointing to the template folder. 
   Create the file `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/user-homes-custom-context.xml` with the new bean definition:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
   <beans>
       <bean name="userHomesHomeFolderProvider" parent="usernameHomeFolderProvider">
           <property name="rootPath">
               <value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.user_homes.childname}</value>
           </property>
           <property name="storeUrl">
               <value>${spaces.store}</value>
           </property>
           <property name="templatePath">
               <value>/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:user_homes_templates/cm:custom_home_root</value>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </beans>
   ```

Now restart Alfresco and create the new user, template content will be copied into the new user home folder (`Repository> User Homes> {user-name}`).

... and if you really must use PHP try [Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP Client](https://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html) or [REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/).